# ros installation fail in osx

Tags: ros, macosx, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello I'm Carlos,

I have a lot of troubles in my ROS installation in OSX.

In first place, I had OSX 'EL CAPITAN'.  But I had a error in the rosdep step, the error was a conflict with qt4 and qt5. Because of this error I had format my Macbook Air, I thought that the error was produced because I had got a lot of apps and libraries in my computer, and now I have OSX 'SIERRA', but I had the problem again.

Then I saw this post:

http://answers.ros.org/question/242518/kinetic-installation-fails-with-failed-to-detect-successful-installation-of-qt5-error/#245782

And I did the rosdep with the --skip-keys argument.

> rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro kinetic -y --skip-keys "libqt5-core libqt5-gui libqt5-opengl libqt5-opengl-dev libqt5-widgets qt5-qmake qtbase5-dev"

Now I solved this error but I have another after with ogre. If I put ogre in --skip-keys then appears other many errors...
The error output is:

> executing command [brew install ogre] Error: No available formula with the name "ogre" ==> Searching for similarly named formulae... This similarly named formula was found: progress ✔ To install it, run: brew install progress ✔ ==> Searching taps... These formulae were found in taps: homebrew/nginx/upload-progress-nginx-module homebrew/php/php55-uploadprogress
> homebrew/php/php53-uploadprogress homebrew/php/php56-uploadprogress
> homebrew/php/php54-uploadprogress Caskroom/cask/progressive-downloader
> To install one of them, run (for example): brew install homebrew/nginx/upload-progress-nginx-module ERROR: the following rosdeps failed to install homebrew: command [brew install ogre] failed
> How Could I solve this?

Thank you.
Regards.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/245811/ros-installation-fail-in-osx./) by [CarlosBarreiro](https://answers.ros.org/users/28260/carlosbarreiro/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2016-10-16

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe that you need to add the taps from OSRF to your Homebrew:

From [ROS Wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/OSX/Homebrew/Source):

```
$ brew tap ros/deps
$ brew tap osrf/simulation   # Gazebo, sdformat, and ogre
$ brew tap homebrew/versions # VTK5
$ brew tap homebrew/science  # others
```

---

Originally posted by [Karl Damkjær Hansen](https://answers.ros.org/users/2205/karl-damkj%C3%A6r-hansen/) with karma: 139 on 2017-06-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0